# PHP function execution takes too much time

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote 60 php arithmetic function for calculating tax. When I execute them, this page its take above 1 min to complete. How to reduce execution time to make the page execution fast?

Comment: What is your version of PHP? what kind of arithmetic functions used?

Comment: please include the code in your question

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: Without a crystal ball, there is no way to answer your question. Do you mean a 60 *line* php function? Where's the function?

Comment: If the problem is really simply the calculation time, i.e. there is no db access involved, then compiling the php could be a solution. For example, facebook uses HHVM (google for HHVM) for this. But in your case I think it is much more probably that you have some trivial debugging trouble what is impossible for us because you didn't include any code into it and obviously you have no idea how this whole thing is working.

Answer (score -1):

SQL index use for retrieve data very fast. You can use sql index for your tables which tables use for query.

You can help from this link. [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question. Admittedly, the question is awful in it's current state, but this answer is in no way helpful.